# finding average dollar amount of an order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find the average dollar amount of an order. I have calculated the average order Total but I need an average that takes into account the fact that not all Orders have a corresponding OrderItems.

This is a homework question and it is as follows:

> What is the average $$ value of an order? To get the answer, you need
>   to add up all the order values and divide this by the
>   number of orders.  There are two possible averages on this question,
>   because not all of the order numbers in the ORDERS table are in the
>   ORDERITEMS table... You will calculate and display both averages.

I have writtern the one ignoring orders with no OrderItem, but not sure of how to go about the second case.

```
    SELECT SUM(OrderItems.qty*INVENTORY.price)  / COUNT(*) AS dollarValue
    FROM Orders, OrderItems, Inventory
    WHERE ORDERS.orderid = OrderItems.orderid AND OrderItems.partid = Inventory.partid
```

[Link To DB Diagram](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55587776/pictures/SalesDB.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Avg` function will not replace `NULL` with zero; it will exclude `NULL` from its calculation. If you have `Order` rows which have no `OrderItem`, you need to use Left Joins. A trick you can use in SQL Server is to nest the joins like so (note the parentheses):

```
Select Avg(OI.Qty * I.Price)
From Orders As O
    Left Join (OrderItems As OI
        Join Inventory As I
            On I.PartId = OI.PartId)
        On OI.OrderId = O.OrderId
```

This will join the `Inventory` table to the `OrderItems` table *before* it Left Joins that result to the `Orders` table. In this way, `OI.Qty` and `I.Price` with both return `NULL` for Orders that have no OrderItems and be excluded from the calculation. An equivalent approach to the above would be to use two Left Joins:

```
Select Avg(OI.Qty * I.Price)
From Orders As O
    Left Join OrderItems As OI
        On OI.OrderId = O.OrderId
    Left Join Inventory As I
        On I.PartId = OI.PartId
```

If you wanted to count Orders with no OrderItems as zero, then you need to covert those nulls to zero using `Coalesce`:

```
Select Avg(OI.Qty * I.Price) As Avg_ExcludingNull
    , Avg( Coalesce(OI.Qty * I.Price,0) ) As Avg_NullAsZero
From Orders As O
    Left Join (OrderItems As OI
        Join Inventory As I
            On I.PartId = OI.PartId)
        On OI.OrderId = O.OrderId
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL has an aggregate function for calculating the average: `AVG()`

```
SELECT AVG(OrderItems.qty*INVENTORY.price) AS dollarValue
FROM Orders, OrderItems, Inventory
WHERE ORDERS.orderid = OrderItems.orderid AND OrderItems.partid = Inventory.partid
```

---

While we're here, may I suggest you use the more modern JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT AVG(OrderItems.qty*INVENTORY.price) AS dollarValue
FROM Orders
JOIN OrderItems ON ORDERS.orderid = OrderItems.orderid
JOIN Inventory ON OrderItems.partid = Inventory.partid
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting I use a JOIN statement if it's a better way to do it I'd be glad to use it. Although this gives me the same answer and doesn't fix the edge case I am looking for.

Comment: Can you give more detail about the edge case? I'm sure I can help you, but I'm unclear on it. Edit the question to add more detail about how you want to calculate the average